# data of current week

Tags: sql, oracle

Identify the total number of customers who have placed an order for the current week. 
how can it be done?

```
select count(*) numberofcustomer from invoice
where invdate=sysdate-7;
```

is this correct?

Comment: You will need to define "the current week". The last 7 days? Or just orders since Sunday? Since Monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks for "...total number of customers...", not total number of invoices. A customer can place multiple orders in a week. I don't know what the name of the field which identifies a customer in your table is - let's assume it's `CUSTOMER_ID`. To get the total number of individual customers you should use `COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID)` as in the following:

```
WITH cteCURRENT_WEEK AS (SELECT NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MONDAY') - INTERVAL '7' DAY AS BEGINNING_OF_WEEK,
                                NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MONDAY') - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS END_OF_WEEK
                           FROM DUAL)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) AS NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS
  FROM INVOICE i
  CROSS JOIN cteCURRENT_WEEK w
  WHERE i.INVDATE BETWEEN w.BEGINNING_OF_WEEK AND w.END_OF_WEEK
```

This assumes that a "week" runs from the first second of Monday through the last second of Sunday. If your business uses different week boundaries you'll have to adjust `cteCURRENT_WEEK` as needed.

Also - the question asks for total number of ORDERS, not total number of INVOICES. An invoice is a shipping document, showing what has been shipped to a customer. An order is an intake document, showing what the customer wants. These are two very different things, and the receipt of an order during a particular week does not mean it will be invoiced during the same week. If you have a CUSTOMER_ORDER table (or something similar) you should probably be using that to determine the number of orders, rather than the INVOICE table.

Best of luck.

Comment: `TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )` will truncate the date to Monday of the current ISO week. So: `SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) FROM Invoice WHERE invdate >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) AND invdate < TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '7' DAY` is simpler.

Comment: @MT0 - not all businesses run on the ISO week. For example, at the company where I work we don't follow the ISO week rules in any official way, although in practice it very nearly always works out that way - but if a sale was made past midnight EST/EDT but before 03:00 AM it would be accounted in the previous calender day's total, rather than on the sale date - so our sale day more-or-less runs from 03:01 AM to 03:00 AM.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `TRUNC` to get the first day of the current week.

This compares MONDAY to SUNDAY

```
where invdate  >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')  AND invdate  < TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW') + 7
```

This compares current WEEKDAY ( MONDAY to FRIDAY )

```
where invdate  >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')  AND invdate  < TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW') + 5
```

Note that the `<` condition is used to prevent overlap.
For example, if you are comparing for the week starting dec-25, it should compare the ranges : `25.12.2017 00:00:00 and 29.12.2017 23:59:59`

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/live/XQLDNE73021)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(*) numberofcustomer from invoice where invdate>sysdate-7;
```

Comment: this is for getting previous week data

Comment: Oh you mean like week starting on Monday for example?

Comment: Do you mean calendar week based on day of week?

Comment: @JohnKane can't get you?

Comment: i need current week data,how do i get it?

Comment: Sysdate - 7 would be based on current time...do you need previous monday-sunday for example?

Comment: @JohnKane yes..

Answer (score 0):

See Oracle next day function...in your case you need to subtract 7 and 14 from the result of the fx